# Use Boost Function as a Class Data Member for Calling Different Member Functions

Tags: c++, boost

This is a toy example from a larger piece of code. the gist is, I am trying to make a boost function based on some input parameter. However, the following fails to compile, with an error message, `no match for call to boost::function<void()> candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided.`

hpp:

```
class SillyClass
{
public:
    SillyClass();
    void sillyFunc1();
    void sillyFunc2();    
    void setUp(bool );

private:
    boost::function<void ()> m_function;
};
```

cpp

```
SillyClass::SillyClass() : m_function()
{
}

void SillyClass::setUp(bool p_in)
{
    if (p_in)
    {
        m_function ( boost::bind(&SillyClass::sillyFunc1, this) );
    }
    else
    {
        m_function ( boost::bind(&SillyClass::sillyFunc2, this) );
    }
}

void SillyClass::sillyFunc1()
{
    std::cout << "Silly" << std::endl;
}

void SillyClass::sillyFunc2()
{
    std::cout << "Not Silly" << std::endl;
}
```

I know the `this` is needed for this to even have a chance of working. If I change the line assigning the function to:

```
boost::function<void ()> f(boost::bind(&SillyClass::sillyFunc2, this));
m_function = f;
```

This compiles just fine. This is the first time I am trying to use boost function for this sort of thing, so I am sure I must be overlooking something. However, the documentation doesn't seem to mention why this fails to compile. Can someone point out to me what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing the initialization syntax in the member-initializer-list of a constructor and normal assignment. This:

```
m_function ( boost::bind(&SillyClass::sillyFunc1, this) );
```

is *invoking* `m_function` with a single argument. But `m_function`'s `operator()` doesn't take any arguments, hence the error (no match for **call** to `boost::function<void()>`, candidate expects **0 arguments**). You instead want to assign it:

```
m_function = boost::bind(&SillyClass::sillyFunc1, this);
```

which should work fine.